# What is going on with Google Fonts' Open Sans

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

A site I'm working on uses Open sans. Suddenly the copy is all in the condensed version. I checked Google Fonts' Open Sans page and this is what I see (see image below). Any idea why the normal font would be condensed? Is this just a weird mistake that Google will quickly fix? How worried should I be about this?

[image: Screenshot of Google Fonts Open Sans fonts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently something had gone wrong with my local version of Open Sans. I guess Google will check to see if you have the font and use the font you have on your computer before trying to download it. Not sure how my font became condensed but re-downloading fixed it. In short, it was just a local problem.

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue. You should mark your answer as the answer to your question :)